# What does it mean, 'this' reference refers to the currently executing object?

Tags: java, oop, this

```
public Class BaseClass{
     public static void parentMethod(){


     }
}

public Class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

     public static void childMethod(){
     }


     this.childMethod();
     this.parentMethod();   

}
```

1) What is the currently executing object in BaseClass?
2) What is the currently executing object in ChildClass?
3) Does the above two this refers to which object?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Comment: This is from Object Oriented Programming 101. Please, do some research first. There are thousands of tutorials out there.

Comment: This code will not compile so none of this questions have any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dilemma here is that "currently executing object" is a very abstract concept that is easy to intuit but hard to describe in writing (at least for me)

If you have a `ChildClass`, it is also a `BaseClass`. Therefore, you have a single object in question. Its type is `ChildClass`, and it can be cast to (and has fields and methods of) `BaseClass` and `Object` as well.

`this` refers to itself. When a `ChildClass` is instantiated, the initializer:

```
 this.childMethod();
 this.parentMethod();
```

executes (though in order for the code to compile, it needs to be in a set of braces).

That initializer calls `childMethod` and `parentMethod` in that order for the object being initialized.